# How do I use GZIP to optimize the size of my web service messages?

Tags: java, web-services, compression, jax-ws, gzip

Is this done at the code level, perhaps through JAX-WS handlers? Or is it done through some configuration at the app server?

I've read something about web compression in general, it appears that just as the message is about to head to the wire, compression is applied. Clients should be able to accept a GZIP MIME type for them to be able to decompress the message.

I'd like to find out who's supposed to apply that compression and how it's done.

Comment: It's the app server, if that server handles HTTP. Otherwise it's the webserver. Search for gzip deflate and $appserver name. For example: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done either by code or by configuring the server to do it on the fly. How it's done with server configuration varies widely depending on the server. For Apache, the tool to use is [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html). The instructions when using JBoss are [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/gzip.html).

To do it in code, you need to:

- compress the data with gzip
- set the `content-length` header to the length in bytes of the *compressed* response
- include the following header in the response:

  ```
  Content-encoding: gzip
  ```
- The request should include the header:

  ```
  Accept-encoding: gzip
  ```

More info can be found in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression).